# SQL RETURNING id always give back 1 as result

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql, codeigniter

i use CodeIgniter and PostgreSQL

I write SQL like this :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO(a,b) VALUES (1,2) RETURNING id";
```

I execute that query like this :

```
$id = $this->db->query($sql);
```

**The question is , why i alway get "1" as return value of the query?** I can sure in database the next value of id (auto increment) is 100 not 1.If i execute that query directly inside phppgadmin the return value is 100 not 1 like execute from my php code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 means `True` and query executed successfully

Use `$this->db->insert_id();` to get the last insert id

Comment: And how to get the id ?

Comment: Am i need query RETURNING inside the SQL ? or i can delete that statement ?

Comment: After $this->db->query($sql) , you need to write $id=$this->db->insert_id();

Comment: I will try your suggestion. However is this way is secure?

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter's **insert_id()** will only return an ID of an **insert()**

Ex:

```
$this->db->insert('posts', $post_data);
$insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

> *Note:* *Insert query will return 0, 1. 0: failure, 1: success*